# C++ generic SqLite 3 table to vector

Tags: c++, sqlite

I just coded method for loading data from SqLite 3 database, it is working and in test run it was successfully checked for no memory leaks:

```
template<typename T>
inline std::vector<T> Database::fill_from_table(const std::string& table_name, const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, void(*)(T &, char *)>>& setters, int64_t limit)
{
    if(!is_open_) throw SQLException("No sql connection");

    typedef void(*setter_t)(T& , char *);

    struct callback_data {
        std::vector<T>& result_vec;
        const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, void(*)(T &, char *)>>& setters;
    };
    callback_data data { std::vector<T>(), setters };

    data.result_vec.reserve(limit == -1 ? row_count(table_name) : limit);

    auto names = column_names(table_name);
    std::stringstream queried_cols;
    for (auto& it = setters.cbegin(); it < setters.cend() - 1; ++it)
    {
        if(std::find(names.cbegin(), names.cend(), it->first) == names.cend())
            throw SQLException("No such column \""+ it->first + "\" in table " + table_name);
        queried_cols << it->first << ", ";
    }
    queried_cols << setters.back().first;

    char *err_msg = nullptr;
    auto query = "SELECT " + queried_cols.str() +" FROM " + table_name + " LIMIT " + std::to_string(limit) + ";";

    auto result = sqlite3_exec(db, query.c_str(), [](void *in_cd, int c, char **col_data, char **n) {
        auto& cd = (*static_cast<callback_data*>(in_cd));
        T item;
        for (int i = 0; i < cd.setters.size(); i++) cd.setters[i].second(item, col_data[i]);
        cd.result.push_back(item);
        return 0; }, &data, &err_msg);

    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
        std::string tmp(err_msg); 
        sqlite3_free(err_msg); 
        throw SQLException(tmp.c_str());
    }

    return data.result_vec;
}
```

where the relevant signatures(implementations can be assumed correct) are:

```
//SQLException.h
class SQLException : public std::runtime_error { ... }
//database.h
class Database
{
private:
    sqlite3 *db;
    bool is_open_;

public:
    const std::vector<std::string> column_names(const std::string& table_name);
    int64_t row_count(const std::string& table_name);

    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T> fill_from_table(const std::string& table_name, const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, void(*)(T &, char *)>>& setters, int64_t limit = -1);
};
```

Firstly, I am concerned about correctness of `const`-ness and (reference) types - arguments, local variables and especially the `struct callback_data` and return type. Regarding `struct callback_data`, there is also question about design - because I was unable to capture local variables to `sqlite3_exec` callback I chose to add this struct.
Also I am not-so-sure about correctness of interaction of custom error handling and SqlLite error handling. The performance is also concern and overall design  involving lambdas be can incorrect(?) because of this. 
What is not important? Sql security(not type safety!) and functionality improvements - i.e. WHERE clause is omitted on purpose. 
*...and of-course, I am always looking to improve my C++ skills, so if you see any errors in parts I did not mention feel free to comment/answer.*

---

usage example:

```
struct TimeStampValue {
    double value, time;
};

auto data = database.fill_from_table<TimeStampValue>("measuredvalues", {
    { "date_time", [](TimeStampValue& i, char* v) { i.time = utils::days_since_1900_ISO_ext(v); } },
    { "value" ,    [](TimeStampValue& i, char* v) { i.value = v ? std::stod(v) : -1.0; } }}
);
```